# Why am I getting a syntax error when using modulo on floats in my fragment shader?

Tags: syntax-error, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm new to using the fragment shader. Why does my code raise a syntax error? I can't understand why it doesn't work. This is the piece of code that raises the error:

```
if ((int) pos.y % 9 == 1) shade = 1;
```

Both `pos.y` and `shade` are floats. I've put `(int)` before `pos.y` so that I could use modulo on it. The error message says this:

```
ERROR: 0:17: ')' : syntax error syntax error
```

I'm taking the error to mean I have **too many** or **to few** brackets, but I checked that and my code seems fine. Why is there an error, and what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLSL is not C. As [stated in the GLSL specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#operators-and-expressions):

> There is no typecast operator; constructors are used instead.

As such, `(int)` is not a thing in GLSL. If you want to convert some float to an `int`, you use constructor syntax: `int(pos.y)`.